# How can I turn a Javascript array of values into an array of Javascript objects by adding the same key for each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to turn something like this:

```
a = ['London', 'Brighton', 'Newcastle']
```

into something like this:

```
b = [{CityName: 'London'},{CityName: 'Brighton'},{CityName: 'Newcastle'}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `a.map(CityName => ({CityName}))`

Comment: @HassanImam - you should capitalize CityName and write as an answer so I can upvote you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` to create an array of object.

```
a.map(CityName => ({CityName}))
```

```js
const arr = ['London', 'Brighton', 'Newcastle'],
      result = arr.map(CityName => ({CityName}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```